# Uploading offline conversion data to AdWords via API is successful but not appearing in the stats

Tags: google-ads, api, conversions, uploading, google-api

I've been trying to upload offline conversions from clicks for quite a while now. First I tried manual uploads from a CSV. I made sure that the click associated with the gclid was at least a day apart from the conversion time. I also made sure that the time format was correct, and the conversion name exactly matched the name of the conversion action. The status of the upload said Finished successfully, but after a few days, the conversion never appeared and the conversion status still said no recent conversions. I made sure I was looking at the correct date range and the that the conversion action was Import from Clicks.

I did some research and discovered that I could also upload conversions with the AdWords PHP API. After setting up the adsapi_php.ini file and triple checking the values, I used this file to test some offline conversion uploads: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201802/Remarketing/Uplo...

After trying to run it many times, I eventually fixed all the errors, and got the message "Uploaded offline conversion value of ..." I did this multiple times with different gclid's to be on the safe side. Over 24 hours later there still seem to be no conversion appearing, however, the conversion action status changed from "No Recent Conversions" to "Recording Conversions." If I hover over recording conversions, it says conversion recorded on January 9th, which is one of the dates of the conversions I passed. However, the All Conversions column still says 0 for the month of January. It's seems like a contradiction and I have no idea what's going wrong since the API said that it was uploading successfully.

And yes auto-tagging is turned on as well, I fully read this page and the pages that it referenced: https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7012522